Cross compile Nodejs 12.22.12 with dynamically linking openssl 3 for 32 bit Linux
I am cross compiling node v12.22.12 for 32 bit ARM Linux embedded system from Ubuntu 22 (host machine). The target system uses openssl v3.x where as node 12.22.12 comes with openssl vl 1.x.
While cross compiling node v12.22.12 is statically bundled with openssl v1.x which is not compatible with target system.
I tried with Node 18.x which has default support of openssl v3.x which is working fine. but avoiding node v18 because it increases size of output binary.
I know there are few options available in node configure like --shared-openssl and others. I am struggling with exact options to use for successful cross compilation with dynamic linking openssl 3 with node 12.22.12.
